# max heapify algorithm from Cormen with zero-indexing

Tags: c, algorithm, heap, heapsort

I am trying to implement max heapify algorithm given in Algorithms Book [here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/)
The algo in book is

```
 MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)
1   l<-LEFT(i)
2   r<-RIGHT(i)
3  if l<=heap-size[A] and A[l]>A[i]
4    then largest<--l
5    else largest<--i
6 if r<=heap-size[A] and A[r]>A[largest]
7    then largest <->r
8 if largest!=i
9    then exchange A[i]<->A[largest]
10        MAX-HEAPIFY(A,largest)
```

My problem is my array is starting at Zero.Where  as in  book they assumed that if index of parent is i then left child is 2i and right child is 2i+1 but that is when their indices start from 1.In my case it is zero so what how should I calculate index of left and right child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left child is at 2i+1, the right child is at 2(i+1) = 2i+2.

You can prove that this is correct by calling your one-based indices j, defining i = j - 1 and observing that

```
j = i + 1
left + 1  = 2j = 2(i+1) = 2i+2
right + 1 = 2j+1 = 2(i+1) + 1
```

so

```
left = 2i+1
right = 2(i+1)
```

(You can also save yourself some trouble by overallocating a single element.)

Comment: @Iarsmans why did you do left+1 and right +1 in above equation.

Comment: @Registered User: I guess you've figured out, haven't you? ;)